# Highlight duplicate pairs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

How would I write a formula that would pick up duplicate pairs:

[image: SO5436865 Q example]

Comment: `A1=B1`? [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54368653/edit) to let us know what the problem is, exactly, would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Select columns A:B and create a conditional formatting rule based on the following formula.

```
=countifs($A:$A, $A1, $B:$B, $B1)>1
```